# How to sort dates and values arrays of respective dates simultaneously in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a usecase where I'll get average data of every day of multiple variables. Dates and values are returned in 2 arrays in unsorted way. I need to sort the dates in ascending order along with the sorted values in Values array. The values which am getting right now are correct as per the dates. But am unable sort the both arrays correctly. i.e, if I try to sort the dates array, am not getting the values respected to a particular date. Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Code Snippet is,

```
let avgValue = [ { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 11 }, value: 19.83 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 10 }, value: 17.88 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 9 }, value: 32.58 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 6 }, value: 1 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 5 }, value: 33.82 } ];

                [ { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 11 }, value: 26 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 10 }, value: 40.38 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 9 }, value: 35.2 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 6 }, value: 2 },
                  { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12, day: 5 }, value: 38.91 } ];

**avgValue is a mongodb query which returns the above array for every variable**

let dates = [ '11/12/2019','10/12/2019','9/12/2019','8/12/2019',
              '7/12/2019','6/12/2019','5/12/2019','4/12/2019'];

let dbValues=[],dbDates=[],concatenatedDate,newdates=[],constArray=[];

let avgDates = avgValue.map((date,i)=>(date._id.year&&date._id.month&&date._id.day)?
                                 constArray.push(date._id.day+"/"+date._id.month+"/"+date._id.year):null);

avgValue.forEach(async data=>{
    concatenatedDate = data._id.day+"/"+data._id.month+"/"+data._id.year;
    dates.map((newDate,j)=>{
       if(!constArray.includes(newDate) && !newdates.includes(newDate) && i==j){
              dbValues.push(0);
              newdates.push(newDate);
       }else if(newDate===concatenatedDate ){
              dbValues.push(data.value);
       }
  });
  dbDates.push(newdates);
}
```

Expected Output is,

**values**:[0,77,1,0,0,200,15,22],

**lables**:[4/12/2019,5/12/2019,
6/12/2019,
7/12/2019,
8/12/2019,
9/12/2019,
10/12/2019,
11/12/2019]

[image]

Comment: Do you use a provided sorting method and you have no duplicate values? Then you can create a map where you link each date to its corresponding value, then sort the date array and finally iterate over it to retrieve for each sorted date its value which you can then place in the correct place in the other array.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the fastest way to do that but if you don't want to implement a sort algorithm you can merge, sort and unmerge the arrays.

```
const values = [22,0,0,15,200,1,77]
const labels = ["11/12/2019","9/12/2019","7/12/2019","10/12/2019","9/12/2019","6/12/2019","5/12/2019"];

// merge
const merged = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    merged.push([values[i], labels[i]]);
}

// sort
merged.sort((a,b) => new  Date(a[1]).getTime() - new Date(b[1]).getTime());

// unmerge
const resValues = [];
const resLabels = [];
for (const mergedValue of merged) {
    resValues.push(mergedValue[0]);
    resLabels.push(mergedValue[1]);
}

// log
// resValues: [ 77, 1, 0, 0, 200, 15, 22 ]
// resLabels: [ '5/12/2019',
//   '6/12/2019',
//   '7/12/2019',
//   '9/12/2019',
//   '9/12/2019',
//   '10/12/2019',
//   '11/12/2019',
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But your solution works for single values array. But I'm getting multiple arrays for multiple variables. These arrays will be returned in a for loop. Every time the loop iterates, it returns an array of values. What would be the solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of achieving this I believe. As the values and labels are not mapped directly except for their index.

One way I could suggest is to extract both arrays and make an array of object combining values and labels (`[{value,label}]`). Then sort and re-assign it to your object.
I've attached a link below on how it could be done. (maybe not the fastest)

The other way is to restructure your original object to have a proper object array instead of different array values as mentioned above so that it could be sorted easily.

https://repl.it/@ParkourKarthik/SortInnerObjects